# Story with a huge robot on the cover covered in moss

Tags: story-identification

Some book I read four years ago, it was about a school for kids with supernatural powers.

I remember that one of the characters could touch inanimate objects and they would talk to her. There was also something about the slightly sinister best friend of the main character who's mind/soul was transferred to a robot after his death.

Something sinister was happening about parties in some underground place in the school and people disappearing during the party itself.

Sorry I can't remember anything else about it...

Comment: Yeah, the book was like charlie bone, but I think for older audiences...